# Cut vector two parts and paste when index is 1

Tags: r, loops, vector

This is the problem. `a` is the vector that will be cut 4 times at the values given in `b`. The two pieces are cut back together in reversed order. However, with `b==1` this gives a problem as can be seen from the output presented. The central problem is that `c(3:4, 1:2)` works fine, but `c(1:4, 1:0)` does not (one 1 too many). How to best solve this without writing too much extra code?

```
a <- c(1:4)
b <- c(3,4,2,1)
d <- NULL

for(i in 1:(length(b))){
  d <- c( d, a[ b[i]:length(a) ], a[ 1:(b[i]-1) ] )
  print(d)
}

[1] 3 4 1 2
[1] 3 4 1 2 4 1 2 3
 [1] 3 4 1 2 4 1 2 3 2 3 4 1
 [1] 3 4 1 2 4 1 2 3 2 3 4 1 1 2 3 4 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just start the last index with a `0` instead of a `1`

```
a <- c(1:4)
b <- c(3,4,2,1)
d <- NULL

for(i in 1:(length(b))){
  d <- c( d, a[ b[i]:length(a) ], a[ 0:(b[i]-1) ] )
  print(d)
}

[1] 3 4 1 2
[1] 3 4 1 2 4 1 2 3
 [1] 3 4 1 2 4 1 2 3 2 3 4 1
 [1] 3 4 1 2 4 1 2 3 2 3 4 1 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
d <- c( d, a[ b[i]:length(a) ], a[ 1:(b[i]-1) ] )
```

your looping function is 1:5. And the `b` just has 4 index